# Java Sound Recorder

Tags: java

I am writing a java program to record sound(using Java Sound API), When I run my code while headphones are plugged in, the program works correctly, but if I remove headphones in the middle the program is neither capturing the sound nor displaying a notification to show that capturing device is not found.
My aim here is to **detect** the removal of the external microphone and automatically switch to the built-in microphone of my laptop computer.

Here is my code:

```
public void capAud() {
    try {
        af = getAudioFormate();
        DataLine.Info dataLineInfo = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class,af);
        td = (TargetDataLine)AudioSystem.getLine(dataLineInfo);
        td.addLineListener(new MyListener());
        new newthread().start();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    }
}
```

And the "newThread" class

```
class newthread extends Thread {

    public void run() {
        baos=new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        int len=32*1024;
        try {
            File file=new File("C:\\Users\\Programmer\\Desktop\\my.wav");

            td.open(af);
            td.start();
            byte []temp=new byte[len];
            while(td!=null) {
                int num=td.read(temp, 0, len);
                if(num>0) {
                    baos.write(temp, 0, num);
                }
              }
            baos.close();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```